# Pandas rolling_apply for List Elements

Tags: python, pandas

I have accumulated counter, whose elements are lists. Each list element is accumulated, compared to the previously row.

```
import pandas as pd
d=pd.DataFrame({'counter': {0: [1,0,2], 1:[1,2,3], 2:[4, 4, 5]}})
```

I can get the maxcounter using the `apply` function.

```
def maxf(x): return max(x.counter)
d['maxcounter']=d.apply(lambda row: maxf(row), axis=1)
```

Now I would also like to have the field "max_increment", get the difference between current row and the previously row, then compute the maximum.  Could we use rolling_apply for this?

The expected output is as below.

```
     counter    maxcounter  increase_max
0   [1, 0, 2]   2   NaN 
1   [1, 2, 3]   3   2
2   [4, 4, 5]   5   3
```

Note: counter is a list, each element is incremented from separated sensor.
This is not optimized structure, but what we get now.

```
     counter    counter_incr    increase_max   max_incr_index
0   [1, 0, 2]   
1   [1, 2, 3]   [0, 2, 1]         2                1
2   [4, 4, 5]   [3, 2, 2]         3                0
```

Comment: What does your question have to do with `rolling_apply`?  If you want the difference between successive values of `maxcounter`, just use `d.maxcounter.diff()`.

Comment: thanks,  but  no the difference in maxcounter.

Comment: @BrenBarn `maxCounter` is a series of lists; I don't see how you can apply `diff` to that.

Comment: Why don't you just store `counter` as three separate columns instead of a column with a list value?

Comment: @BrenBarn "store counter as three separate columns" is better, but the list is what I am getting.

Answer (score 1):

> get the difference between current row and the previously row

Since your type is not numeric (it is a list), it seems the easiest thing is to perform a [`pd.Series.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.shift.html) followed by an operation subtracting each element from the previous one:

```
import numpy as np
>>> [(np.array(c) - np.array(p)) \
    for c, p in zip(d.counter, d.counter.shift(-1))]
[array([ 0, -2, -1]), array([-3, -2, -2]), array([ nan,  nan,  nan])]
```